# Throw the exception when unable to navigate in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

Myq question is, element is visible and clickable also but unable to navigate to the next page, in selenium for the same issue there is a ElementNotInteractableException. But i need to throw the same exception using JavaScript.

How to throw exception in Playwright JavaScript?

Comment: The use case here is a bit vague. Are you testing or scraping? If testing, `await expect(page).not.toHaveURL(urlBeforeClick);` seems like it should work. If scraping, take an action on a locator on the next page after clicking, and if it times out, you didn't navigate.

Comment: Its a testing, on playwright

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.